# GPU goes out of memory during training large dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am using a Transformer network for machine translation, during training of model the GPU runs out of memory during large dataset, it works fine with small data.

This is the self attention part, The error comes during the computation of matrices.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, head):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.head = head
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.head_dim = embed_size // head

        assert (self.head_dim * head == embed_size), 'size of head_dim is not matching'

        self.query = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.head_dim, activation='linear', use_bias=False)
        self.value = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.head_dim, activation='linear', use_bias=False)
        self.key = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.head_dim, activation='linear', use_bias=False)
        self.fc_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.embed_size, activation='linear')

    def call(self, value, key, query, mask):
        # Number of training examples
        N = query.shape[0]
        query_len, value_len, key_len = query.shape[1], value.shape[1], key.shape[1]

        # Reshape according to the number of examples and words
        query = tf.reshape(query, (N, query_len, self.head, self.head_dim))
        value = tf.reshape(value, (N, value_len, self.head, self.head_dim))
        key = tf.reshape(key, (N, key_len, self.head, self.head_dim))

        query = self.query(query)
        value = self.value(value)
        key = self.key(key)

        # energy shape: (N, head, query_len, key_len) try to imagine the shape in mind
        energy = tf.einsum("nqhd, nkhd->nhqk", query, key)

        if mask is not None:
            energy = energy * mask
            energy = tf.where(tf.equal(energy, 0), -1e20, energy)

        attention = tf.keras.activations.softmax(energy, axis=3)

        # attention shape: (N, head, query_len, key_len)
        # value shape:(N, value_len, head, head_dim)
        # output: (N, query_len, head, head_dim)
        output = tf.reshape(tf.einsum("nhql, nlhd->nqhd", attention, value), (N, query_len, self.head*self.head_dim))

        output = tf.keras.activations.linear(output)

        return output
```

The error is

```
2021-09-20 11:51:49.615495: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1036] 1 Chunks of size 35477760 totalling 33.83MiB
2021-09-20 11:51:49.615502: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1036] 1 Chunks of size 40866304 totalling 38.97MiB
2021-09-20 11:51:49.615509: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1036] 1 Chunks of size 47409664 totalling 45.21MiB
2021-09-20 11:51:49.615516: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1036] 1 Chunks of size 47547136 totalling 45.34MiB

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6860   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6861   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6862   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6863   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6864 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,334,25335] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:BiasAdd]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator to load just a part of the dataset in the GPU memory and with that you will be able to train with your model.

Here is an example of a simple generator for image classification that you need to adjust to your use for NLP:

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(32,32,32), n_channels=1,
                 n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('data/' + ID + '.npy')

            # Store class
            y[i] = self.labels[ID]

        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

And then pass it to `.fit`

```
params = {'dim': (32,32,32),
          'batch_size': 64,
          'n_classes': 6,
          'n_channels': 1,
          'shuffle': True}

# Datasets
partition = # IDs
labels = # Labels

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(partition['train'], labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition['validation'], labels, **params)

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Comment: I am using already using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train, label) command for the dataset.

Comment: How much GPU memory do you have? If you are already using a way to load just a part of your dataset into the memory, try reducing batch size. It seems that you are using batch size of 32. Also reducing the sentence length or (now 334?) and word count (now 25335?) will help.